# WPF Add file extension in image source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I'm working on a WPF / XAML project in Blend there I have 2 items:

1. TextBlockDesign with the value "TSM"
2. Image

I need the Image Source for the Image to be `TSM.png`

And I need to get that `TSM` from the `textbox`

So the Imagesource should be `[TextBox].png`

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve that by utilizing a binding and a converter.

The Binding takes the value from the Textbox and converts it using a converter.

Try this:

```
<Control.Resources>
    <my:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="sourceConv" />
</Control.Resources>
<TextBox x:Name="txtTSM" />
...
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Text,ElementName=txtTSM,Converter={StaticResource sourceConv}}" />
```

The converter class could look like this. Note that you have to implement the string to ImageSource conversion by yourself. I have no access to VS right now, so there might be some little bugs in it.

```
public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // convert string to image source
        String filename = string.Format("{0}.{1}",(string)value,"png");
        return new ImageSource(filename);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got a <UserControl.Resources> but when adding <my:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="sourceConv" /> i get an error telling me ImageSourceConverter does not exsist. I did create the class and added xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

Do i need something more?

Comment: No, this should be sufficient. There could be two things going wrong I can think of: Either the class does not exist in the `WpfApplication1` namespace or you did not recompile your application (these kinds of errors tend to disappear after building the application).

Comment: I think i've got that right, please take a look at my file tree;
http://imgur.com/Mc4J7Hs

Allso the code you provided in a .cs file looks like this;
http://pastebin.com/R03vxthm

I know the converter doesn't work yet, but i need to get it working in at all before i proceed.

Thanks a lot for your help! Been working in C# for a while, but i'm pretty new to Blend :)